# Video driver reports 8-bit color depth after Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, windows-update, aero

Windows Update pushed out a new video driver for the Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family. One HP 6730b laptop was updated from 8.15.10.1872 to 8.15.10.2021. After the update the color depth is reported as 8-bit even if the setting is 32-bit. This means that Areo effects are disabled.

Downgrading to 8.15.10.1872 did not help.

Is there any way to force the video driver to report 32-bit color depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to roll back the driver and go to the [HP support website](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodNameId=3687780&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3687777&submit.y=7&submit.x=4&lang=en&cc=uk) and make sure you are up to date with the latest driver listed that they provide. Laptop drivers are not always standard as they can be modified to optimize the display for the fitted hardware.